# Using line numbers in revision mode with balloons in Word 2007 without counting the lines in the balloons?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have to use balloons in my document in revision mode.  But it seems that word counts each text of line in the balloons as separate lines, so that page 1 may end with line number 23 and page 2 begins with line number 41 as there were 18 lines of text in the balloons.  How can I keep the balloons but have the line numbers continue from page 1 to page 2 without counting the lines in the balloons?  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have "Original Showing Markup" enabled under the Review tab. This would cause the line numbering to become disjointed since you are not looking at the changes that effect the line numbering.

The solution is to change the view to "Final showing markup" or to accept all changes. Then the line numbering will appear correct.